# Tim value using dataweave in mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am trying to trim / from below payload.

payload:
{
"drive" : "Dev",
"rootPath" : "/Devtest"
}

Am trying below

numValue: payload.rootpath.numValue replace "/" with ""

but giving me error how can i achieve this?

expected output:

"Devtest"

Answer (score 1):

Please, try with the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.rootPath replace "/" with ""
```

Note that this expression will replace all occurences of /. So, if rootPath is /root/subdir, the result will be rootsubdir.